# How to lock the position of one of my bones?

Tags: bones

I want to move some of my bones without moving the entire rig. Is there a way to do this without unparenting the bones?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should explain more precisely what is your case. But for example, you could unparent your bone in *Edit* mode, then in *Pose* mode, give it a *Child Of* constraint (press the *Set Inverse* button to keep the bone at its original position). When you'll need the child bone to be unparented, you'll simply create 2 *Influence* value keyframes: at frame X-1 you'll keyframe an *Influence* of 1, and at frame X you'll keyframe an *Influence* of 0.

[image]